# How to change Facebook app visibility

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I've built an iOS app that uses Facebook Login.  I've been having trouble getting user_friends permissions to work (getting the friends of the user that have used the app).  I realized that it has to do with the App Visibility (NOT the visibility of posts).  When a user logs into my app with Facebook, the Facebook App Visibility defaults to "Only Me".  For the life of me, I cannot find a place to change this.  There have been answers to similar questions, pointing to the developer page for the app, but there's no place to set the app visibility.

Does anyone know how this visibility is set and how to modify it?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is not such thing as “app visibility”. Your app is either live, or in development mode. But that should not affect whether users that can successfully log in can see their friends that are also users of the app.